# show that $S= \cup_{n \in K}(n, n+1] : K \subset Z.\ is\ \sigma-algebra.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

show that $S= \{\cup_{n \in K}(n, n+1] : K \subset Z.\  is\ \sigma-algebra\}.$

We need to prove the followings.

1. $\emptyset \in S$
2. $if \ A\in S \ then\ A^c\in S$
3. $If\ A_i\in S\ then \ \ \cup A_i\in S \ where A_i\ are\ disjoint\ sets.$

for $\emptyset \in S\ since \ \emptyset=\cup_{n \in K}(n, n+1] \ where\ K\ is\ a\ empty\ set.  $

My concern is to show $A^c\in S$

let $A=\cup_{n \in K}(n, n+1]$ consider $A^c=\cap_{n \in K}((-\infty,n]\cup (n+1,\infty))$

It seems $A^c$ is not in the S. it has a different form. Am I not seeing something here?

Comment: Hint $A^c$ will correspond to the set $K^c$. To see this,
Enumerate the elements in $K$ s.t. $a_1 < a_2 < .. $. Then
$S = (a_1, a_1 + 1] \cup (a_2, a_2 + 1] \cup ... $ and $S^c = ... (a_1 - 1, a_1] \cup (a_1 + 1, a_1 + 2] \cup ..$

Comment: Yes. That is nice observation for $A^c$. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kaind wrote, we have
$$\left(\bigcup_{n\in K} (n,n+1]\right)^c = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus K} (n,n+1] .$$

Another way to see this: we have the equivalence
$$x \in \bigcup_{n\in K} (n,n+1] \iff \lceil x-1\rceil \in K $$
(where $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function).

Then
$$\begin{align*}
x \in \left(\bigcup_{n\in K} (n,n+1]\right)^c &\iff x \notin \bigcup_{n\in K} (n,n+1] \\
&\iff \lceil x-1\rceil \notin K \\
&\iff \lceil x-1\rceil \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus K \\
&\iff x \in \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus K} (n,n+1] 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's makes lot of sense. Thank you @hgmath